# QEMU automatically exit

Tags: linux, bash, qemu

I want to exit QEMU shell using some script.
The idea is to exit without typing manually `CTRL + A`, then `X`.
I want to do that inside the script, automatically.
I want to use `CTRL + A`, then `X` inside the script, is it possible?

Comment: `kill -TERM`? Or set up a control socket. No reason to try to emulate keyboard input for a program that explicitly has control interfaces meant to be used by other software.

Comment: https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/QMP -- once you've tried using the documented interfaces yourself, come back and ask a question about a specific problem you encounter, should one take place. Without deciding which interface/mechanism you want to use, this isn't close to specific enough of a question to be on topic here.

Comment: Hi, I use QEMU for emulation, then I want to exit QEMU and show the results, 
but now it stays on shell. I don't want to see and access the user to that shell.
Did you get my point?

Comment: I think so -- but I don't see how any part of that point means that my comment above doesn't apply in full.